# What additional attributes can I put in a <li> tag?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing some jQuery magic and I need to tag a `<li>` to do something special. I can't use class or id due to certain other constraints. What other attributes can I put in there so jQuery can find the element?

Comment: Why can't you use class?

Comment: you can use a css class. The css class need not exist.  It will act as a "marker" unless or until you remove it. If you show your code there may be other options to suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Title is a valid attribute that you might be able to use.

If HTML5 is an option, you might want to try data attributes: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: using the data attributes is really the way to go and was created for this exact use case.

Comment: +1, You can also use data attributes in selectors, although they will probably perform substantially worse than native ones: `$('[data-something="blah"]')`. Thus narrowing down the selection first with proper class/ID selectors is strongly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the title attribute.  Why can't you use classes?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I posted the same answer as the guy above within seconds of each other, yet I receive a negative score and he receives a positive one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any param and find like this:
$("[param=smth]")

Answer (score 0):

Also If You think, that you can't use class because li already have any class, you are wrong because yo can add multiply classes to any element
class="a b c" and find in jQuery by any class

Comment: It's because the view passes the tag through and strips classes before adding new ones. Drupal = retarded. Especially the set up we're using.